# ARDL Unit root df

Tags: unit-root, differencing, ardl

When applying ARDL
I used Dickey-Fuller unit root test, and found variables integrated at I(1) and I(0).
For running the ARDL model do I use my original data (not differenced) or do I use the differenced data?

Comment: No need to difference in an ARDL.

Comment: OK, it is just to make sure it's not I(2) then